# How do I implement WebSockets from scratch with the .NET 4 Framework (and nothing else)?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Ok I want to build a simple chat app where people can go a url, type in a name and a message and click submit and it will basically show that message to everyone that is current connected.

Firstly i would like to state i've had zero experience in sockets programming and the like. I'm simply a web 2.0 person building websites with css/html/js/ajax and backend i have asp.net on vb and sql server for database.

The many tutorials i've read linked me to http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/

I've downloaded it, but im totally lost. i can't get the samples working and i don't even know what to run.

So basically coming from an ajax background, i was wondering why do we even need to download any additional stuff to do web sockets? I mean in ajax i can simply create a `asd.aspx` file and use `Response.Write(text)` (text based on the input which are available through dissecting the url) and voila, the server side is done, all that's left is just to create `new XMLHttpRequest` and stuff in the client side.

So ok I'm not worried about the client side part of Web Sockets. but the server side part of web sockets is just difficult. so in the client side i have this: `ws://localhost:8080/websocket`. Is it true that it will work if is also an .aspx file as such: `ws://localhost:8080/websocket.aspx` ?

I'm wondering so how do i continue from here? in Ajax i will supply parameters from client in the url as such: `page.aspx?a=1&b=2` and do output in the server using `Response.Write` it's all clear but how do we do it in web sockets?

I mean of course i do not demand a full explanation with a forum reply but if someone could link me to a tutorial/book that actually does explain these stuff it would be great.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? it sounds like you are trying to re-invent the wheel for no good reason. If I didn't use open source third party libraries and insisted on writing my own implementations every time, I don't think I'd manage to deliver anything to my clients before their patience ran out and they fired me!

Comment: Why don't you look at the source code of http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com ?

Comment: the documentation page is empty http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/documentation. i've had no idea how to even implement it and fit everything together in one big picture. it's like everyone already know what to do with the download but i don't. i've got zero experience in socket programming. my only experience is web 2.0 with html5/css/ajax and aspnet + sql server as backend

Comment: there are samples in the source code, they might help

Comment: So, what do you want? Do you want to implement the Websockets protocol yourself? If so, read the associated RFCs. But as @Adam said, there is no good reason for doing so. If you only want to know, how to USE superwebsockets, you should ask exactly that.

Comment: i'd like both. is it recommended to create a new thread?

Comment: Since you don't know either, I would recommend taking the path of least resistance and pursuing superwebsocket. Ultimately all your code operates through many layers of abstraction and the question is:- which abstractions do you trust? Unless you spend a *lot* of time writing, testing and reviewing your own implementation, it's highly likely that it won't be as reliable or bug-free as superwebsocket. And yes, I would create a seperate thread for that (and consider closing this question).

Comment: "simply create a asd.aspx" ... "and voila, the server side is done" - this is because IIS (or whatever webserver you use) is doing the connection management for you.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis so does it mean that if we want to use web sockets we had to do the connection management ourselves? are web sockets such a big jump in difficulty compared to ajax?

Comment: I just meant to illustrate that if you see these libraries as "additional stuff", IIS is the "additional stuff" you need for aspx to work. I haven't used WebSockets, but I can imagine it being a big jump in compared to Ajax as Ajax requests are exactly the same as regular requests (regarding the server), where these websockets are asynchronous.

Comment: if you can help me out with this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436426/woes-in-trying-to-set-up-a-web-socket-connection-in-net thnkx

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's implementation has a full chat client sample for both HTML5 and pure C#.

http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/prototypes/websockets/websockets/download

I'm guessing this implementation is what would end up in ASP.NET and .NET framework so I'm using it because of that.