# woes in trying to set up a web socket connection in .NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have my index.aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="index.aspx.vb" Inherits="Web_Socket.index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var stockTickerWebSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:14970/ws");
        stockTickerWebSocket.onopen = function (evt) {
            alert("Stock Ticker Connection open …");
        };
        stockTickerWebSocket.onmessage = function (evt) {
            alert("Received Ticker Update: " + evt.data);
        };
        stockTickerWebSocket.onclose = function (evt) {
            alert("Connection closed.");
        };
        stockTickerWebSocket.postMessage("TEST MESSAGE");


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and so basically i guess i will need to create a file that points to ws://localhost:14970/ws? What file would it be? (probably a stupid question, but since it doesn't have an extension..)

I've had this code from somewhere, WebSocketServer.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace WebSocketServer
{
    public enum ServerLogLevel { Nothing, Subtle, Verbose };
    public delegate void ClientConnectedEventHandler(WebSocketConnection sender, EventArgs e);

    public class WebSocketServer
    {
        #region private members
        private string webSocketOrigin;     // location for the protocol handshake
        private string webSocketLocation;   // location for the protocol handshake
        #endregion

        public event ClientConnectedEventHandler ClientConnected;

        /// <summary>
        /// TextWriter used for logging
        /// </summary>
        public TextWriter Logger { get; set; }     // stream used for logging

        /// <summary>
        /// How much information do you want, the server to post to the stream
        /// </summary>
        public ServerLogLevel LogLevel = ServerLogLevel.Subtle;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the connections of the server
        /// </summary>
        public List<WebSocketConnection> Connections { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the listener socket. This socket is used to listen for new client connections
        /// </summary>
        public Socket ListenerSocker { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the port of the server
        /// </summary>
        public int Port { get; private set; }


        public WebSocketServer(int port, string origin, string location)
        {
            Port = port;
            Connections = new List<WebSocketConnection>();
            webSocketOrigin = origin;
            webSocketLocation = location;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the server - making it listen for connections
        /// </summary>
        public void Start()
        {
            // create the main server socket, bind it to the local ip address and start listening for clients
            ListenerSocker = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
            IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, Port);
            ListenerSocker.Bind(ipLocal);
            ListenerSocker.Listen(100);
            LogLine(DateTime.Now + "> server stated on " + ListenerSocker.LocalEndPoint, ServerLogLevel.Subtle);
            ListenForClients();
        }

        // look for connecting clients
        private void ListenForClients()
        {
            ListenerSocker.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);
        }

        private void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult asyn)
        {
            // create a new socket for the connection
            var clientSocket = ListenerSocker.EndAccept(asyn);

            // shake hands to give the new client a warm welcome
            ShakeHands(clientSocket);

            // oh joy we have a connection - lets tell everybody about it
            LogLine(DateTime.Now + "> new connection from " + clientSocket.LocalEndPoint, ServerLogLevel.Subtle);



            // keep track of the new guy
            var clientConnection = new WebSocketConnection(clientSocket);
            Connections.Add(clientConnection);
            clientConnection.Disconnected += new WebSocketDisconnectedEventHandler(ClientDisconnected);

            // invoke the connection event
            if (ClientConnected != null)
                ClientConnected(clientConnection, EventArgs.Empty);

            if (LogLevel != ServerLogLevel.Nothing)
                clientConnection.DataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedFromClient);



            // listen for more clients
            ListenForClients();
        }

        void ClientDisconnected(WebSocketConnection sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Connections.Remove(sender);
            LogLine(DateTime.Now + "> " + sender.ConnectionSocket.LocalEndPoint + " disconnected", ServerLogLevel.Subtle);
        }

        void DataReceivedFromClient(WebSocketConnection sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Log(DateTime.Now + "> data from " + sender.ConnectionSocket.LocalEndPoint, ServerLogLevel.Subtle);
            Log(": " + e.Data + "\n" + e.Size + " bytes", ServerLogLevel.Verbose);
            LogLine("", ServerLogLevel.Subtle);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// send a string to all the clients (you spammer!)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">the string to send</param>
        public void SendToAll(string data)
        {
            Connections.ForEach(a => a.Send(data));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// send a string to all the clients except one
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">the string to send</param>
        /// <param name="indifferent">the client that doesn't care</param>
        public void SendToAllExceptOne(string data, WebSocketConnection indifferent)
        {
            foreach (var client in Connections)
            {
                if (client != indifferent)
                    client.Send(data);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Takes care of the initial handshaking between the the client and the server
        /// </summary>
        private void ShakeHands(Socket conn)
        {
            using (var stream = new NetworkStream(conn))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                //read handshake from client (no need to actually read it, we know its there):
                LogLine("Reading client handshake:", ServerLogLevel.Verbose);
                string r = null;
                while (r != "")
                {
                    r = reader.ReadLine();
                    LogLine(r, ServerLogLevel.Verbose);
                }

                // send handshake to the client
                writer.WriteLine("HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake");
                writer.WriteLine("Upgrade: WebSocket");
                writer.WriteLine("Connection: Upgrade");
                writer.WriteLine("WebSocket-Origin: " + webSocketOrigin);
                writer.WriteLine("WebSocket-Location: " + webSocketLocation);
                writer.WriteLine("");
            }


            // tell the nerds whats going on
            LogLine("Sending handshake:", ServerLogLevel.Verbose);
            LogLine("HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake", ServerLogLevel.Verbose);
            LogLine("Upgrade: WebSocket", ServerLogLevel.Verbose);
            LogLine("Connection: Upgrade", ServerLogLevel.Verbose);
            LogLine("WebSocket-Origin: " + webSocketOrigin, ServerLogLevel.Verbose);
            LogLine("WebSocket-Location: " + webSocketLocation, ServerLogLevel.Verbose);
            LogLine("", ServerLogLevel.Verbose);

            LogLine("Started listening to client", ServerLogLevel.Verbose);
            //conn.Listen();
        }

        private void Log(string str, ServerLogLevel level)
        {
            if (Logger != null && (int)LogLevel >= (int)level)
            {
                Logger.Write(str);
            }
        }

        private void LogLine(string str, ServerLogLevel level)
        {
            Log(str + "\r\n", level);
        }
    }
}
```

so now my question is how do i *connect* the `WebSocketServer.cs` to the `index.aspx` ?

As a start, all I'm trying to accomplish is just to get the Web Sockets working, and have the connection established, which then will `alert("Stock Ticker Connection open …");`

Comment: You'd run the server which would listen on the configured port.  Then run the ASP.NET app, navigate to the page, and it would open the socket connection.  I don't see how else it could possibly work?

Comment: what do you mean running the server which would listen on the configured port? Isn't the ASP.NET app the server itself (like when we do AJAX we do not have to run any servers right)?

Answer (score 0):

WebSocketServer.cs should be run in a separate application, e.g. console app or Windows Service.  You call `Start()` on that, and it listens for connections from clients.  ASP.NET isn't involved.  You could use a regular HTML page: it's the Javascript code that acts as the client.

You'd also need to consider that clients will need to be able to connect to the server address on the port given - so think about firewalls, routing, etc.

For what it's worth there aren't many advantages to using a web socket in this case.  You could use AJAX instead, then you wouldn't have to worry about:

- Firewall setup your side
- Proxy servers the client side
- Managing multiple connections yourself
- Serialisation/deserialisation
- Target browser platform supporting WebSockets

The advantage of WebSockets, as far as I can see, is a lower latency, lower bandwidth and greater control.  But if this is a real-world app with many users you'd better get your support department in gear before using a WebSockets solution..

Comment: You could take a look at my project here: https://github.com/Alxandr/Reverser. It has basic support for websockets, but I don't know if it's the best way to go. I start the websocket-server on a separate thread **from** ASP.NET, so it still runs under the IIS-worker I think, and has access to some variables xD.

Comment: @Alxandr: long-running processes under ASP.NET/IIS are not a good thing.  The worker processes should deal with requests then finish up as quickly as possible.

Comment: Yeah, but it's not running on the thread-pool. I've made an async http-handler that deals with both the websocket and the long pooling requests. Though I am considering launching it as a separate server altogether using something like kayakhttp.com maybe.

Comment: Maybe I should just have IIS launching a new process... That way I could get over some command-arguments, and maybe some basic IPC.

Comment: The ideal/appropriate solution is to have a Windows Service or long-running console app (Windows Service is easier and better to manage, log, startup, configure etc), and use inter-process communication where required (that's WCF, Remoting, Named Pipes, etc).

Comment: thanks for helping me. but i'm still abit confused. do you mean the asp.net server and the server running the web socket are not the same server, and they can't be the same server?

Comment: ASP.NET has nothing to do with Web Sockets.  They are not HTTP and are a different technology.  Whatever you choose to run the Web Sockets server might run on the same PC/machine as the ASP.NET app, but they are different things.

Comment: @Kieren great how did you know all these stuff? do you have any books to recommend? http://www.google.com/#q=websockets&hl=en&authuser=0&prmd=ivns&source=lnms&tbm=bks&ei=cK0CTqMLx9CtB6TSmbYK&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=6&sqi=2&ved=0CB8Q_AUoBQ&prmdo=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=bdad51d155896486&biw=948&bih=471 didn't give much hope..

Comment: I knew nothing about web sockets before seeing this question.  However, I did know that sockets are not a technology ASP.NET has much to do with (well, low-down it does but ASP.NET is HTTP).  Can't think of any books but you could search 'web sockets' I suppose.

Comment: Websocket is http.... But it's not compatible with ASP.NET, I was thinking about trying to write it in Kayak or something like that.